# React state updating without reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

My problem is simple to understand.

I have an userlist in my state. Filled by a DataBase call.
And I also have a selecteduser filled when a element in the userlist is clicked.

When this element from userlist is clicked, a modal is opening with input with a default value filled by selecteduser.

I assigned onChange function to those input, then each change is saved in selecteduser.

But the problem is, each change is also saved in userlist and I really don't understand why.

This userlist doesn't have any setState in the code except for the data call from the database.

```
class Users extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
   this.state = {
    userlist: [],
    selecteduser: [],
    IsModalUserVisible: false
   };
 }
```

Then call and store data in userlist.

```
 componentWillMount() {
 db.collection("user")
 .get()
 .then(collection => {
   this.setState({
     userlist: collection.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
   });
 });
}
```

Here is the onChange from the input

```
handleChangeEmail(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const selectedUserUpdate = this.state.selecteduser;
 selectedUserUpdate.email = event.target.value;
 this.setState({
  selecteduser: selectedUserUpdate
 });
}
```

And here the function called onClick on a userlist element.

```
UserSelected(user) {
 this.setState({
    selecteduser: user,
    IsModalUserVisible: true
  });
}
```

The userlist.map to show the user list.

```
{this.state.userlist.map(user => {
  return (
    <UserItem
      callback={() => this.UserSelected(user)}
      key={user.email}
      email={user.email}
    />
  );
})}
```

And for finish, the user manage modal, opened on click to an user list element.

```
<ManageUserItem
   isOpen={this.state.IsModalUserVisible}
   email={this.state.selecteduser.email}
   changeEmail={this.handleChangeEmail.bind(this)}
/>
```

So, when I change the email inside the input, I can see on background that the list also change. And I checked with a console.log(this.state.userlist) in the handleChangeEmail, I can see the userlist is updated too.

I wanted to be clear, but i hope it's not to long to read.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userlist: collection.docs.map(doc => doc.data())` creates a Javascript Array that at each index holds a memory reference point to the data returned by `doc.data()`. When you initialize the `<UserItem>` component, you are providing this component with the same memory reference in the `userlist` state Array. When a user is clicked, that same reference is passed through the `callback` prop method `UserSelected` and in that method the same memory reference is assigned to the state variable `selecteduser`. Later on when the email change is handled for that selected user, the method `handleChangeEmail` is operating on a memory reference stored in two places, the `userlist` Array and the `selecteduser` Object. When you update an attribute of an Object reference, any other place that Object is referenced will show such a mutation because they are pointing to the same underlying data. One minor alteration that I would suggest for this code is in the `constructor` method, initialize `selecteduser` to be an Object ({}) not an Array ([]) since `selecteduser` is eventually assigned an Object anyway and not an array. Finally, if you'd prefer that `selecteduser` not be the same Object reference as what is referenced in the `userlist` Array, you may create a new Object (and thus a new Object reference) from each Object referenced in the `userlist` Array. Like so:

```
{this.state.userlist.map(user => {
   // this is one way to do it, you can find others elsewhere on SO for more complex cases.
   // Look into, Javascript as a pass by reference language versus pass by value languages
   // and their nuances. 
   const newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))
   return (
    <UserItem
      callback={() => this.UserSelected(newObject)}
      key={newObject.email}
      email={newObject.email}
    />
  );
})}
```